# How to Select all Items and Their Most Recent Values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this kind of table schema

```
DateTime | Item | Value | Active
--------------------------------
date1      i1     23       1
date2      i1     25       0
date3      i1     25      -1
```

Only inserts are performed and the 'Active' column means: 1 created, -1 deleted, 0 value changed . The point is to get all items still active at a certain date and that's easy with `group by(Item) having sum(active)>1` but what I want is to also get the most recent value of an active item.

So, in this example it would be:

- for a time interval ending with date1 the value should be 23
- for a time interval ending with date2 the value should be 25
- for a time interval ending with date3 there should be no result

My Sql is not very strong so I need a bit of help with the query (or maybe a different approach of storing/doing things) of getting all the active items and their more recent value relative to a given start/end date.

Comment: Shouldn't the value be undefined when the date is less than `date1` and 23 between `date1` and `date2`?

Comment: Sample data and results with actual dates might be a bit clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You can express this in SQL Server using `outer apply`:

```
select t.*
from table t outer apply
     (select top 1 t2.*
      from table t2
      where t2.datetime > t.datetime
      order by t2.datetime asc
     ) tnext
where @date >= t.datetime and
      (t.datetime < tnext.datetime or tnext.datettime is null) and
      t.status <> -1;
```

Comment: Doesn't do what I want but it gave me a hint of how to tackle the problem. I've managed to come up with a query that does what I want.